# Separating By Post Category in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently attempting to build a model using Ruby on Rails. As of now, I am trying to separate posts based upon their 'tags' (which is a column in my posts model) - I want all 'sports' articles, for example, to pop up on a separate page. Tags are assigned to a post via text-field. However, I can't seem to come to a conclusion as to how I'd be able to complete this task.

Here is some code I've tried out within my posts model:

```
def self.getTag
  find(:all, :include => params[:tags], :order => 'created_at DESC')
end
```

However, it seems as if `params[:tags]` is an invalid argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params` is not available (and should not be used) in the model. Just pass a parameter to the model method:

```
# controller code
Model.getTag(params[:tags])

# model code
def self.getTag(tags)
  find(:all, :include => tags, :order => 'created_at DESC')
end
```

Comment: The way in which I want to implement the code, is for Sports articles to be on a separate link (in the nav bar) entitled Sports. Thus, how do I get it so that when I click on sports, all the sports articles show up I guess i'm just a bit confused as to how the parameter gets passed in.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. The GET and POST parameters are accessible in the controller, and you can pass them as arguments to model methods - just like I showed. If you're still confused I would suggest reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: @AllanNørgaard I see it's still used in the docs - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html Anyway he didn't give any kind of details about his environment.

Comment: @draevor That's true. Im sure I saw someone state, it's deprecated now. Gotta look that up.

Comment: @draevor You're right. Its only deprecated without futher arguments, e.g. find(:all). My bad

Comment: @dreavor I guess i'm asking how I should code the Sports view in order for the tagged items to show up.

Comment: That's an entirely different question which requires another answer. Just post another question detailing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you are looking for, but it seems like a pretty easy one :-)

```
#controller (e.g. /articles/sports)
def sports
  @a = Articles.sport
end

#model
def sport
  where(:section => :sport)
end

#view
<td>
  <%= @a.title >
  <%= @a.body >
</td>
```